# Retrieve all named ES6 imports

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is there any way to retrieve a list of all named ES6 imports?

**For example:**

```
import { A } from 'file_A';
import { B, C } from 'file_B';

let { A, B, C } = imports; // Where imports is a fictional system object
```

Comment: There are already variables named A,B and C, I don't see why you would want to declare them again. Also, what do you mean by name? The variable name? The name of the file?

Comment: I would like to reference them all in one go using the spread operator, I declared them twice to demonstrate the question. Named as opposed to default imports.

Comment: In what environment would these imports be used (node, browser)? I'm guessing it would have a bearing on whether this is possible.

Comment: @OliverRadini typically browser

Comment: @Alex But what is wrong with the explicit imports of all names? What do you need that object for?

Comment: @Bergi I am using this within Redux containers where I have many named actionCreators from different files and I would like to use the spread operator within bindActionCreators() to reduce boilerplate. Estus' answer works perfectly for this as tree shaking is not so important for such small functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be achieved in ES2018 with object spread syntax:

```
import * as fileA from 'file_A';
import * as fileB from 'file_B';

let { A, B, C } = {...fileA, ...fileB};
```

Or with `Object.assign` in ES6:

```
let { A, B, C } = Object.assign({}, fileA, fileB);
```

In case of bundling tools (Webpack, Rollup) this forces all exports to be included into a bundle and kills tree-shaking optimization.

Notice that multiple `default` exports or other exports with same names won't be available this way.

Comment: This works perfectly for what I need despite limitations, as explained in comments above, thanks.